# Border is not working on button in android studio

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

code for button is:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/applyfilter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#00dec6"
        android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
        android:text="APPLY" />
```

code for buttonshape.xml file

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">

    <gradient android:startColor="@color/navcolor"
    android:endColor="@color/navcolor"
    android:angle="270" />

    <corners android:radius="20dp"/>

    <stroke android:color="#00dec5"
    android:width="5px"/>

</shape>
```

I have used the custom drawable file to add a border around the button, but the border is not getting applied on button. Can somebody help me ?

Comment: Use AppCompatButton instead of Simple Button

Answer (score 1):

You should try with this I can see like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztiFi.png)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="20dp" />
            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#00dec5" />
            <gradient android:angle="270" android:endColor="@color/purple_500" android:startColor="@color/purple_500" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Thanks!